# Use of specific target_country and country meta tags

Tags: html, accessibility, meta, user-experience

The guidebook written by the Brazilian government regarding good practices in web development recommends using the following meta tags:

```
<meta name="target_country" content="br" /> 
<meta name="country" content="Brazil" />
```

It does not provide any explanation for why we should use them, though. The guidebook is a 10 years old document; there are visibly outdated codes there. However, that was not the case with those two meta tags: I could not find whether they are recommended or deprecated by W3C. I could not even find if they actually *exist*, to begin with.

Are the meta tags `target_country` and `country` useful? If so, what for? Are they endorsed by W3C, or considered a good practice by any other relevant institution, browser, social network etc.? Do they help increasing accessibility?

Comment: I did some searches and nothing came up. It could be someone with limited reach trying to establish a new standard. There are about six pages of results though I'm not seeing anything official looking any where. The performance page on my site (link in my profile) will be updated with more website performance metrics in a few days though I've never seen this until *this* post. I say don't worry about it. If you need to add geographic data (like an address or mentioning of your territory, city, etc) that will help search engines much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

Remove them if allowed, they are not valid and serve no purpose.

### Long Answer

These definitely aren't part of the current spec for HTML5, I would guess they are HTML4 (if they were even relevant then, people did like to make up meta tags!)

[Over on the wiki](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions) I can see that both "country" and "target_country" do not exist.

If you really need to display some form of location data use `geo.country` or `geo.region` etc. However [Google ignores these anyway.](https://blog.seoprofiler.com/googles-geo-meta-tags-web-pages/) so I am unsure if they have much use.

The only thing that I can think they may have been relevant for was for identifying the language of the page, but in HTML 5 you should be using the [lang attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/lang#:%7E:text=The%20lang%20global%20attribute%20helps,for%20Identifying%20Languages%20(BCP47).) on the HTML tag anyway.

Comment: I've checked the HTML5 spec, the HTML4 and the XHTML, but couldn't find anything relevant, either, so I was wondering whether it was used by some search engine, or somewhere else.

Comment: There is a book called "SEO for 2011" and it states that `meta name="country"` is important for search engines such as Bing. I have dug through a few pages of Google but no real references to it other than that.

Answer (score 1):

Forget Brazil for a moment because internet standards apply all over the world. That being said, I have never came across that tag in last 2 decades. Looks like outdated information and you shouldn't be worried about it. If (and it's a Big IF) they have made some kind of crawler or a directory/search engine themselves which does gives priority to this tag then it will be just limited in scope to that crawler/directory/search engine.

Comment: I'm aware internet standards apply all over the world, I just wanted to provide context when I mentioned the guidebook. I really don't know why they recommended using those meta tags, because, as far as I am aware, there's no specific search tool developed by the Brazilian government.